# Linux Ubuntu Bash - Find words containing more than 2 vowels using AWK regular expressions

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I want to print all the words containing more than 2 vowels from a file using awk.

This is my code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat $1 | awk '{   #Default file separator is space 
for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)  #for every word          
  {
  if ($i ~ /([aeiojy]){2,}/)            
    {
      print $i
    }
}}'
```

Regular expression is the problem

/([aeiojy]){2,}/) this is my actual idea, but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

This should work with GNU `grep`:

```
grep -Poi '([^[:space:]]*?[aeiou]){3,}[^[:space:]]*' file
```

Options:

```
-P perl compatible regular expressions
-o output every match on a single line
-i case insensitive match
```

The regex:

```
(                start of subpattern
  [^[:space:]]*  zero or more arbitrary non whitespace characters
  ?              ungreedy quantifier for the previous expression (perl specific)
  [aeiou]        vowel
)                end of subpattern
{3,}             the previous expression appears 3 or more times
[^[:space:]]*    zero or more other characters until word boundary.
```

---

Btw, perl compatible regular expressions are actually not required here. With plain `grep` you can use:

```
grep -oi '\([^[:space:]aeiou]*[aeiou]\)\{3,\}[^[:space:]]*' file
```

---

Note: I've excluded punctuation in the above examples but it can be added if required.

Comment: Thank for reply! Just needed to change 3 to 2(2+ vowels). Grep is fine, but isn't it possible with awk?

Comment: You are welcome. However, your question says *more than two*. That means at least 3 vowels.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Good job anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` function in `awk`:

```
awk -v RS=' ' 'split($0, a, /[aeiouAEIOU]/) > 2' file
```

- `-v RS=' '` will process each word separated by space as separate records.
- `split` will return value greater than 2 if there are at least 2 vowels in the word.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Have you tested it? This prints everything, words without vowels too. As far as I remember the split function puts the first argument(whole line($0) in this case) into array 'a' , sperated by the third argument which is vowel. So We end with words separated with vowels yes? It doesn't work :P

Comment: I don't post awk commands without testing. [Check this working demo](http://ideone.com/9HGixu)

Comment: On Ubuntu try this: `awk -v RS=' ' 'split($0, a, /[aeiou]/) > 2' file`

Comment: @anubhava Can you explain why your first version does not work on Ubuntu?

Comment: @MichaelVehrs: That is because default awk that is shipped with ubuntu is not gnu-awk and that's why it doesn't support `[[:blank:]]` regex as record separator.